# Error log not visible through windows explorer

Tags: php

I am unable to view the error log file or the log folder itself . By running phpinfo() through a php file on localhost , I am able to get the path of error log file as C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log, both for **local value** and **master value** .

I am unable to understand why the log folder itself is not visible in c:\xampp\php, while it is being shown by phpinfo() .

I have added a jpg file along with this question which shows :

- The path of the error log file through phpinfo().
- A snaphot of PHP directory under c:\xampp folder which doesn't show the log
  folder itself.

I couldn't find an answer to my question on any one of the sites on the internet including stackoverfow . There were questions and answers in stackoverflow which addresses the problem of error log not working . But I couldn't find an answer 
to my problem where the log folder itself is not visible .

**I have downloaded xampp 5.6.21 .**

Any help will be appreciated.[image]

Comment: The error log is usually excluded from the document path because it reveals information that should not be visible to thrid party. You can use `echo nl2br(file_get_contents("C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"));` in any script to output the raw content.

Comment: When i tried running the above code , I got a warning :
failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testproject\err_log.php on line 2 . 

Is there any other way of accessing the error log file ?

Comment: Did you try to create the log folder?

Comment: thanks..now it works..I created a seperate logs folder in c:\xampp\php folder . Then I tried testing out a php file with some syntax errors . The php_error_log containing the error description was automatically created and placed .in the logs folder .I also tested it out with multiple php  files in different folders and the errors were all logged in the php_error_log file . Also , I found out that the following syntax works(notice how the path is written) : 
echo nl2br(file_get_contents("C:/xampp/php/logs/php_error_log")); 
The syntax with C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log gives me an error .

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow..i would like to upvote your answer and accept it .Can you please post this as an answer ?

Comment: also..if you feel that my question can be a value add to junior developers or beginners ..you could upvote my question ..:)

Comment: Sorry about the backslashes, I do almost never any code on windows systems. Backslashes are escape characters in PHP strings (for example, `\"` prints a " even if the string is "-delimited). Of course, the path would have to be written like `c:\\path\\to\\file` or `c:/path/to/file` (as you already found out).

Answer (score 1):

I am sharing my findings as an answer to my question . These findings are based on some valuable inputs provided by **syck**. Here are my findings :

- **Path of error log file using phpinfo()** - If you run phpinfo() through a php file on your localhost, the path of the error log file is displayed . In my case it was "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log".
- **logs folder needs to be created** : Even though the path of error log file is displayed by using phpinfo(), PHP doesn't create the logs folder on its own . We need to create the logs folder in c:\xampp\php folder . It is only then that the php_error_log file is automatically generated by PHP, and placed in the logs folder, when an error or warning occurs in any one of our PHP files.
- **Visibility of error log file** : The php_error_log file is visible through the windows explorer once the logs folder is created and the error log file is generated and placed in the logs folder.
- **Output the raw content of the error log file** : We can output the raw contents of the log file by using   nl2br(file_get_contents("C:/xampp/php/logs/php_error_log"));